# multilanguage ASP.NET web site with subdomains?

Tags: asp.net, localization, resources

I have a web site supporting Multi-language and I have a list of resources for each country my site supporting ex:

1. Site.ar-BH.resx
2. Site.ar-SA.resx
3. Site.ar-EG.resx

Ihe problem is that now I need to run with multiple sub-domains on the same application and I need to have for each sub-domain different resources:
ex:

- Site.ar-BH-subdomain1.resx
- Site.ar-SA-subdomain1.resx
- Site.ar-EG-subdomain1.resx
- Site.ar-BH-subdomain2.resx
- Site.ar-SA-subdomain2.resx
- Site.ar-EG-subdomain2.resx

But unfortunately I can not do the previous as it gives me the following error: project contains a definition for the class.

> " Compilation Error Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
>   review the following specific error details and modify your source
>   code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0101: The namespace 'Resources' already
>   contains a definition for 'Site'"

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the codebehind of the resx files in the resx.cs you will find that it did not rename the actual class when you renamed the files. You need to go through them and rename the class as well.

Comment: i already did that and the error above faced is while browsing the page and it is not a build error